# jsp:usebean identifier error

Tags: jsp

```
<jsp:useBean id="employee" 
    class="com.delhiguru.test.dto.EmployeeBean" 
    scope="request" />
```

While executing this I get this error:

```
unknown type for identifier employee
```

My bean class is `com.delhiguru.test.dto.EmployeeBean`

My main task is to fetch values from beanclass in the JSP page.

Comment: Could you post the EployeeBean java code? May be a problem like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8287051/840635

Comment: Are you sure the package name is correct and the Bean is within your pathname? Try to clean and recompile, republish to the tomcat. And make sure the class is in your `target` directory.