# The value for the useBean class Student is invalid

Tags: java, netbeans, javabeans

**I've found many questions with my same title, but no one was helpful.**

I am trying to run a JSP page that should load a class, but I am getting this error:

[image]

I see many questions answered with "the class should be into the WEB-INF directory", but the problem is that Netbeans doesn't allow to create packaged into that folder. Packages are in the "Source Packages" directory, so I've put it there. I created a package named "Package", with a class "Student" inside it:

```
package Package;

import java.beans.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author ramy
 */
public class Student implements Serializable {

    public static final String PROP_SAMPLE_PROPERTY = "sampleProperty";
    private String sampleProperty;
    private PropertyChangeSupport propertySupport;

    public Student() {
        propertySupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);
    }

    public String getSampleProperty() {
        return sampleProperty;
    }

    public void setSampleProperty(String value) {
        String oldValue = sampleProperty;
        sampleProperty = value;
        propertySupport.firePropertyChange(PROP_SAMPLE_PROPERTY, oldValue, sampleProperty);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        propertySupport.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }
}
```

And this is the JSP:

```
<%@page import="Package.Student" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <jsp:useBean id="student" class="Student" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I also tried many other ways, like writing  and removing the import directive, or creating a folder named "classes" inside the WEB-INF directory, with a folder (not a package) named "Package" inside it, but nothing to do. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: Can you try this way, <jsp:useBean id="student" class="Package.Student" /> See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97336_01/buslog.102/a83726/genlovw3.htm#1008181

Comment: From the error description it seems that your program is not able to find the student class. You can try @Abi's suggestion. It should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The value for the useBean class attribute is invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287051/the-value-for-the-usebean-class-attribute-is-invalid)

Comment: @lostInTransit My class has a public constructor with no arguments, I've read many questions with the same title as mine before asking the question, but no one helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, you should modify the usebean tag to use full classname as the class attribute value. So, you should use Package.Student as your class value. BTW, convention is to start the package name with lower case character, so you should change it to package.Student..

Then, use ANT or even better, Maven to create a WAR file for you. It will by default put all your classes in proper place like WEB-INF/classes/Package/Student.class... If you don't have that much time, just create WAR file with the hirarchy {WARROOT}/WEB-INF/classes/Package/Student.class.. When your WAR is deployed on web server say tomcat, you should not get this exception...

Hope it helps

Comment: The first paragraph of the answer was enough to solve the problem.